# Retrieving source code from a website with Python

Tags: python, hyperlink

I've been trying to extract links from a website with no luck. From what I've read it can be done easily, but the links are with a pop-up dialog within the website. The only way I can grab the links would be to ctrl-A and view the source to copy.

Is there a way to Select all before grabbing the entire content?

Appreciate any information or pointers!

*EDIT* I would like to avoid downloading anything beyond what python already has, e.g BS/Scrapy etc.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! For best results in getting your question answered we generally suggest writing a MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Stedy note that `[mcve]` is automagically expanded to: [mcve]

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

As far as retrieving links are concerned, it can be done using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) and [bs4](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) as suggested by jonrsharpe. I am excited in answering this because, i wrote one of them 1 or 2 days ago.

```
from sys import argv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#from notify2 import notify2
from time import sleep
import notify2
def send_message(title, message):
    notify2.init("Init")
    notice = notify2.Notification(title, message)
    notice.show()
    return

url = "http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=%s&sort=newest" % argv[1]
while True:
    r = requests.get(url)
    while r.status_code is not 200:
            r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
    data = soup.find_all("link")
    question = data[2].get('href')
    question = question[question.find('questions') + 19:]
    send_message("Question %s: " % argv[1].upper(), question)
    sleep(60)
```

Basically, this a script which gives you desktop notifications every 1 min. The data which is shown is the *first question of specified tag of stackoverflow* (in most of the cases it works just fine, you have to check for correct url in others) 
Here, you can reach a url and get all the data using `requests.get()` and parse those data using different methods given by `bs4` 
By the way, the repo of this code is [here](https://github.com/vivekanand1101/so-desktop-notification). Any contributions would be appreciated.